# ideas to animate several individual parts of a large graphic

Tags: jquery, html, flash, css, animation

I have a large graphic at the top of a page. It's a bunch of logos, with each one sitting on its own little section of the graphic.  I'd like for new logos to rotate into place every 4 or 5 seconds, with a loop of 3 or 4 logos for each spot.

The animation for each logo would simply be one logo replacing another in that specific part of the image.  A fast but smooth slide in from above would be ideal.

What would be your method of choice?

Thanks!

Austen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution using Greensock: http://jsfiddle.net/brian_griffin/zquLC/ 
I believe it does exactly what you asked for. Please note you have to include the first logo twice in order to make a perfect loop.

This can also be done using CSS3 animations, but Greensock is supported in older browsers.

(pseudo)HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="logo" id="firstlogo">
        <img 1/>
        <img 2/>
        <img 3/>
        <img 1/>
    </div>
    <div class="logo" id="secondlogo">ditto</div>
    <div class="logo" id="thirdlogo">ditto</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.logo {
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: -300px;
}
img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

JS

```
var spd = 1.5 //seconds
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=0px"})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=100px"})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=0px"})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=100px"})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=0px"})
tl.to('firstlogo', spd, {top:"+=100px"})
```

Comment: Wow, Brian - that looks great!  Thanks so much.  So, noob question:  what's the drill; net suggested Greensock first, but you supplied functioning code that I can use a start point.  Who should I tick?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm new here, too.

Tick whoever comes after and offers a proper CSS3-only solution :)

Comment: lol - yes, i was thinking about responsiveness, but that would've seemed ungrateful!  :-)

Comment: I think Brian earned the tick. Good work, and have a +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Greensock animation platform (GSAP)](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/). It's a tween library which was originally developed for ActionScript and has now been ported to JavaScript. It's incredibly powerful with support for delays, staggers, repeats, loops, reverse etc., and has been, more or less, the industry standard for animation in Flash for the last 4 or 5 years.

The timeline functionality will probably be of particular interest to you as it makes choreographing the type of animation you've described above an absolute breeze. For example, it will allow you to group a collection of individual animations together and play them back, loop, repeat and reverse them as if they were a single animation.

Comment: Thanks net - I'll take a look now.  Cheers.